# FFMPEG combine PNGs of different size into movie

Tags: ffmpeg, png

Is it possible to combine PNG of different heights without rescaling (like tile does)?
I have pairs of images of same width, but first has height 900px and second 200px. I would like them to merge into 1100px height image preserving their sizes (tile gives 50-50% split).

Is it possible to merge images from two folders? If there are inputs like -i folder1/%d.png -i folder2/%d.png ffmpeg treats this as one sequence followed by another. I would like it to be merged pairwise (folder1/1.png with folder2/1.png and so on).

Comment: Combine them into frames first, then pass preprocessed frames to ffmpeg.

Comment: The main goal is using ffmpeg if this is possible. Since tile is working, maybe there are some more advanced filters. Also this should be less time consuming than splitting into different parts. Currently I am merging them using GD library, but it takes several hours and needs a lot of free disc space. So I am explicitly asking if it is possible to do it in ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: boring representation of overlay of two image sequences of same width and different height]

<sub>Boring representation of overlay of two images of same width and different height</sub>

Use the [vstack](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i dir1/%d.png -i dir2/%d.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]vstack,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

- I added the [format](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to ensure that the output uses a chroma subsampling that is compatible with non-FFmpeg based players; otherwise `ffmpeg`, depending on many factors, attempts to minimize or avoid subsampling which is technically often desired but not for playback with dumb players. This is the same as using `-pix_fmt yuv420p` that you may see in other examples, but I prefer to use it in a filtergraph if I do any other filtering.
- `-preset` and `-crf` control the encoding speed and output quality. See the [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info on these options.
- `-movflags +faststart` will re-locate the `moov` atom from the end of the file to the beginning once encoding is finished. Typically used if your viewers are watching via progressive download in a browser or similar.

Comment: Thank you once more. This is really awesome because in GD library I have got less than one merge in 3 seconds. The same material goes on your solution at 20 fps on ffmpeg, and all the work is done in one program - it is over 70 times faster and saves two different programs into one. ;)